# Как в Postgresql хранить координаты карт?

Tags: postgresql, yandex-maps-api, google-maps, карты, геолокация

Подскажите, каким лучше способом хранить координаты точек для карт в Postgresql и есть ли способ так же хранить не точку, а область?
Дело в том что хочется сделать, что б человек, желающий указать адрес- указывал адрес(точку либо улицу), а человек, не желающий отображать адрес- мог бы ограничиться городом.
Как такое можно сделать? Это несколько полей нужно или можно в одном поле таблицы сделать?
Спасибо

Comment: postgresql из коробки позволяет хранить геоданные. Читайте доку п. 8.8. "Geometric Types". https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-geometric.html

Comment: @alex Встроенные типы для геоданных не очень подходят, гораздо лучше для этого подходит расширение postgis https://postgis.net/docs/